# How do I *properly* run an asyncio/aiohttp request in a loop?

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-requests, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I am trying to request a bunch of URLs concurrently however the URLs are built from a list. Currently I am looping over the list and (I think) adding them to the queue as it happens. It is definitely 10x faster than requests.get, however I am not sure I am doing it correctly and so it can be optimized. I profiled it and noticing it is still locking 90% of the time after the concurrent requests are done i.e start -> 10+ concurrent requests -> lock for 5 seconds or so -> done

Additionally, this code results in a `Unclosed client session` message at the end. Any idea why? Pretty sure this is using a context manager properly.

I have searched and not found this exact question

```
 import signal
 import sys
 import asyncio
 import aiohttp
 import json
 import requests

 lists = ['eth', 'btc', 'xmr', 'req', 'xlm', 'etc', 'omg', 'neo', 'btc', 'xmr', 'req', 'xlm', 'etc', 'omg', 'neo']

 loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
 client = aiohttp.ClientSession(loop=loop)

 async def fetch(client, url):
     async with client.get(url) as resp:
         assert resp.status == 200
         return await resp.text()

 async def main(loop=loop, url=None):
     async with aiohttp.ClientSession(loop=loop) as client:
         html = await fetch(client, url)
         print(html)

 def signal_handler(signal, frame):
     loop.stop()
     client.close()
     sys.exit(0)

 signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)
 tasks = []
 for item in lists:
     url = "{url}/{endpoint}/{coin_name}".format(
                     url='https://coincap.io',
                     endpoint='page',
                     coin_name=item.upper()
                 )
     print(url)
     tasks.append(
         asyncio.ensure_future(main(url=url))
     )

 loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*tasks))
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like what you have works, but as you thought you're not doing everything quite correctly:

- you create a client which you never use, and don't close correctly (causing the `Unclosed client session`) warning
- you're creating a client for each request which is much less efficient than reusing a client.
- you're not running most of your code in a running event loop.
- the signal handler as you have it is not necessary, if you have long running asyncio tasks you might want to use [`add_signal_handler`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html)

Here's my simplified take on your code:

```py
import asyncio
import aiohttp

lists = ['eth', 'btc', 'xmr', 'req', 'xlm', 'etc', 'omg', 'neo', 'btc', 'xmr', 'req', 'xlm', 'etc', 'omg', 'neo']


async def fetch(client, item):
    url = 'https://coincap.io/{endpoint}/{coin_name}'.format(
        endpoint='page',
        coin_name=item.upper()
    )
    async with client.get(url) as resp:
        assert resp.status == 200
        html = await resp.text()
        print(html)


async def main():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as client:
        await asyncio.gather(*[
            asyncio.ensure_future(fetch(client, item))
            for item in lists
        ])


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

If you want to then process the html, you can either do it inside the fetch coroutine or operate on all the results from `gather`.

Comment: Great answer, just one minor nit: `create_task()` should be used in preference to `ensure_future()` if you know you have a coroutine object - [rationale by Guido](https://github.com/python/asyncio/issues/477#issuecomment-268709555). And in this case neither is needed because `asyncio.gather` (and `asyncio.wait` etc.) will correctly handle being passed coroutine objects, or any other objects that can be converted to `Future`.

Comment: yes. I meant to change it but forgot, in this case `ensure_future` will just call `create_task`, but still better to use `create_task`.

Comment: But here you don't need it - `asyncio.gather(*(fetch(client, item) for item in lists))` should work just fine. `gather` is [explicitly documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather) to accept coroutines or futures.